# Grey Screen when I run my code but background music still plays

Tags: ios, xcode

I ran my app on the IOS simulator but all I get is a greyed out screen but the background music plays. I tried rewriting the code to see if it was a bug that I and Xcode missed but nothing changed. Any guess on why the screen is greyed out but the music still plays in the back would be great.

Comment: You would have to add some code to show what you are actually doing, for example how you setup the mentioned music player.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a read of the guide to [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which usually involves supplying code in the form of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without more context and code to go by, it will be unlikely anyone can or will help you.